# Show Trend line in Kendo Bar Chart using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I 've spent almost one week  on this and can't seem to have any idea how to solve it.

I am trying to create a bar chart with trendline on it like this:

[Trendline in Bar Chart](http://dojo.telerik.com/APEjU/4)

Here is some code(jSON String) of my App:

```
 var arr = [20, 60, 10, 50, 25];
            var avg = [];
            var total = 0, thisAverage = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                    total += arr[j];
                }

                thisAverage = total / (i + 1)
                avg[i] = thisAverage
            }
```

And Here is my JSON string of in AngularJS:

```
jsonString += "\"series\": [{";
            jsonString += "\"type\": \"bar\",";
            jsonString += "\"name\": \"BAR Chart\",";
            jsonString += "\"stack\": " + true + ",";
            jsonString += "\"color\":\"Red\",";
            jsonString += "\"data\": \""+arr+"\",";
            jsonString += "}, {";
            jsonString += "\"type\": \"line\",";
            jsonString += "\"name\": \"Line Chart\",";
            jsonString += "\"stack\": "+true+",";
            jsonString += "\"color\":\"blue\",";
            jsonString += "\"data\": \"" + avg + "\",";
            jsonString += " }],";
```

Any help on this? Please give me solution to create a trend line in kendo bar chart?

Comment: Why are you manually creating the JSON string? Never* do that, you can just convert object to JSON string and vice versa using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Actually I am working on project which is already developed like this, Now I have to show just TrendLine in Kendo Bar Chart. I can't change this structure. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: You did not say what the problem actually is. Are you getting an error in the console? Can you create a DOJO that reproduces your issue?

Comment: There is no console error, but code is not working. I didn't find anycode regarding this on google.